# In FBX file, I cannot understand difference between Transform and TransformLink

Tags: 3d, direct3d, 3dsmax, fbx

I am very new to FBX and not familiar in this area since I just started to study it

In the FBX SDK reference guide, It says :

```
Transform refers to the global initial position of the node containing the link

TransformLink refers to global initial position of the link node
```

But I cannot understand the definition.

Also what's the difference between "node containing the link" and "link node"

The document is too unfriendly to study FBX... Can I get some help?

In advance Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

An FBX mesh can be expected to have only one skin *deformer* object for animation purposes. Think of this as a deformable version of the mesh.

The deformer contains *clusters*, and each cluster in turn contains a *link* (or joint).

These objects are extracted from the mesh as follows:

```
VOID FbxLoader::LoadMeshBoneWeightsIndices(FbxMesh* pMesh, Mesh& mesh)
{
    // A deformer is a FBX thing, which contains some clusters
    // A cluster contains a link, which is basically a joint
    // Normally, there is only one deformer in a mesh
    // There are many types of deformers in Maya,
    // We are using only skins, so we see if this is a skin
    FbxSkin* currSkin = (FbxSkin*)(pMesh->GetDeformer(0u, FbxDeformer::eSkin));

    UINT numberOfClusters = UINT(currSkin->GetClusterCount());
    for (UINT clusterIndex = 0u; clusterIndex < numberOfClusters; ++clusterIndex)
    {
        FbxCluster* clusterPtr = currSkin->GetCluster(clusterIndex);
        UINT numOfIndices = UINT(clusterPtr->GetControlPointIndicesCount());
        DOUBLE* weightPtr = clusterPtr->GetControlPointWeights();
        INT* indicePtr = clusterPtr->GetControlPointIndices();
        std::string currJointName = clusterPtr->GetLink()->GetName();
        std::string secondName = clusterPtr->GetName();
        UINT boneIndex = BoneNameToIndex(currJointName);
        FbxAMatrix transformMatrix;
        FbxAMatrix transformLinkMatrix;
        FbxAMatrix globalBindposeInverseMatrix;

        // Now that we have the clusterPtr, let's calculate the inverse bind pose matrix.

        // The transformation of the cluster(joint) at binding time from joint space to world space
        clusterPtr->GetTransformLinkMatrix(transformLinkMatrix);
        clusterPtr->GetTransformMatrix(transformMatrix); // The transformation of the mesh at binding time
        // find out if we need geometryTransform
        globalBindposeInverseMatrix = transformLinkMatrix.Inverse() * transformMatrix; // * geometryTransform;

...
```

Back to your question, the code sample also extracts the *transform* matrix, and the *transform link* matrix:

- The transform matrix is a local-to-world space transform of the mesh vertices
- The transform link matrix is a local-to-world space transform of the joint

Each is used to arrive at the global bind pose inverse matrix as shown.

```
globalBindposeInverseMatrix = transformLinkMatrix.Inverse() * transformMatrix;
```

For each new frame of a skeletal animation, a bone offset matrix must be generated for each bone in the skinned model... and that offset matrix is
*globalBindposeInverseMatrix*. Just load it into each bone's offset matrix member for every new frame of animation, for example:

```
LoadOffsetMatrix(globalBindposeInverseMatrix, mBoneVector[boneIndex].offset);
```

The offset matrices are packed together into an array, usually referred to as the *bone matrix palette*.
And it's this bone matrix palette which is sent to the vertex skinning shader to update the skeletal model animation each frame.

Comment: An FbxMesh usually has more than 1 deformer in my experience....  (e.g. originalMesh -> blendShapeDeformer -> skinDeformer -> FFDDeformer, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @robthebloke. I've updated my answer by specifying skin deformers only.